# How to create a launcher to show recent files

Tags: desktop

I think it would be convenient to be able to quickly bring up a list of my most recently accessed files. This could be done by opening nautilus and then clicking on recent in the left panel, but I would like a faster way of doing it. One improvement would be to pass an argument to nautilus to have it show you the recent files when it starts up, analogous to how `nautilus ~` opens nautilus in the home directory.

But the solution to my problem doesn't even have to be a file manager. I think the optimal thing for me would just be a desklet that when I click it, a little menu showing all my recent files shows up. Is there a way to do this?

I have linux mint 17.1 xfce. I don't see a way to do it on the whisker menu. I tried some called cairo dock, which does an applet called "shortcuts", which you can right click on and a menu comes up, and one choice from this menu is to open nemo to show a list of recent files.

Is there any easier way to do this without the extra clicks? Again I think the easiest thing would be to create a launcher to a file manager with a command line argument to get it to show recent files, but I am open to any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is:

```
nautilus recent:///
```

so if you create a launcher called `recent-files.desktop`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Recent files
Comment=Show recent files in Nautilus
Exec=nautilus recent:///
Icon=file-manager
Terminal=false
```

in `~/.local/share/applications`, you will be able to show recent files with just one click instead of two clicks.
Alternatively, you could use:

```
gvfs-open recent:///
```

to open recent items with your default file manager (`Dolphin`, `Thunar` etc). I only have `Nautilus` installed so I can't test it with other file managers.

Comment: This pretty much does what I want. But it seems to only work with gnome applications. For example, if I do `nautilus recent:///` then, in the resulting nautilus I can open a `.txt` with either `gedit` or `kate` (by right clicking the file and selecting `Open with...`). However, if I do `thunar recent:///`, then I can only open text files with gedit; if I try to use `kate` I get an error message "Could not start process Unable to create io-slave: klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'recent'. Meanwhile conqueror can't even dispaly the recent files: it gives me an improperly formatted URL error.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs - well, `recent :///` is a [gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) URI so obviously, _it is_ gnome-specific. Non-gnome apps might not work properly (but thunar should work natively with Gio/gvfs). I have no idea whether it is a inter-process communication issue or those KDE apps don't fully support/understand gvfs. The only desktop I'm familiar with is Gnome so I don't know what to say...